# ISAPI Filter modifies 302 response - IIS drops request and puts into HTTPERR - IPv6 / HTTP2.0

Tags: iis

Need some help to dig deeper into why IIS is behaving in a certain way.  Edge/Chrome makes an HTTP2.0 request to IIS, using the IPv6 address in the header (https://[ipv6]/) which results in the server generating a 302 response.  The ISAPI filter makes some mods to the 302 response and replaces the response buffer.  IIS drops the request/response and logs in HTTPERR log:

```
<date> <time> fe80::a993:90bf:89ff:1a54%2 1106 fe80::bdbf:5254:27d2:33d8%2 443 HTTP/2.0 GET <url> 1 - 1 Connection_Dropped_List_Full <pool>
```

Suspect related to HTTP2.0, when putting Fiddler in the middle, it isn't HTTP/2.0 anymore, it downgrades to HTTP/1.1 and it works.

When using an IPv4 address, it works.  In either case the filter goes through the identical steps.  There is no indication in the filter that anything went wrong.

Failed Request Tracing will not write buffers for incomplete/dropped requests that appear in HTTPERR log.

Is there a place where I can find out more detailed information about why IIS is dropping the request?

I did the network capture, and looks like browser is initiating the FIN tear down of session.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any load balance or reverse proxy before request get in IIS? This error indicates that the log cannot store more lost connections, so the problem is that your connection is lost.

1. If you use load balance, web application is under heavy load and
   because of this no threads are available to currently provide
   logging    data to HTTP.sys. [Check this](https://blogs.iis.net/chrisad/connection-dropped-in-http-sys-error-log-an-explanation).
2. Or before IIS response to client, client has closed the request but
   IIS still send response. This is more likely to be a problem with the
   application itself not IIS and http.sys. [Check this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/6a7e7efd-528f-5b16-6114-e0101c78084e).

One thing I noticed is if you change http2 to 1.1, it can work well. The difference between http1.1 and 2 is performance.

> HTTP/1.1 practically allows only one outstanding request per TCP connection (though HTTP pipelining allows more than one outstanding request, it still doesn’t solve the problem completely).
>
> HTTP/2.0 allows using same TCP connection for multiple parallel requests

So it looks like that when you use http2, one connection includes multiple requests and application cannot handle these requests well, especially the request of image.

Aother thing is failed request tracing can catch all request and response, including  status code is 200 and 302.

Comment: I was setting up a network capture to confirm whether the client reset the connection.  All my computers rebooted overnight because of a Windows Update (and Wireshark required a reboot too).  When I went to repro the issue, the issue did not reproduce.  Maybe the restart did something.  I will see if there are other computers available to repro, and see if network tracing can uncover any more info.  Failed Request Tracing doesn't write out partial trace logs for these type of errors, and HTTPERR logs lack sufficient detail - making it difficult to determine where issue is.

Comment: I was using the wrong browser... it repros on Edge but I was using IE.  I did repro it, and captured the trace, and I was expecting to see a reset, but instead it looks like the client does initiate the FIN tear down of session.  Because data is encrypted, not much to see.  I don't think I can put the screen capture here in the comment, so I will try editing the post to add the screen capture there of the network trace, in case it stirs some ideas.

Comment: This is not a problem with IIS but a browser. Because Edge actively initiated FIN teardown, the connection was disconnected, instead of IIS disconnection. Just like you use IE, there is no such problem.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to find more information about how to troubleshoot this issue with Edge.